# Republishing custom message to type /PoseArray

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node which publishes a custom message (BoundingBox3d.msg) displaying the coordinates of a detected human,

```
string Class
float64 probability
float64 x
float64 y
float64 z
```

and another custom message (BoundingBoxes3d.msg) with that array

```
std_msgs/Header header
BoundingBox3d[] bounding_boxes
```

However i would require it to be published as a posearray message type, because another node requires the input to be of type geometry_msgs/PoseArray. The node (Darknet3D.cpp) produces the output values x, y and z and I have been trying unsuccessfully to publish the values into a different message type. All the comments with //M Test are the additional code written by me.

When I rostopic /posearray, the values of the posearray are all blank.

```
header: 
  seq: 682
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
  frame_id: ''
poses: []
```

Could anyone point out why I am not able to get values for my posearray? I am pretty new to coding so all my attempts have been comparing different open source codes and improvising for my needs. I tried using `ROS_INFO("poseArray size: %i", posearray.poses.size())` to see if the size of the posearray, but it remains as 0. The other pose.x etc values all returns correct values.
Below is the cpp file which outputs the values

```
#include "darknet_ros_3d/Darknet3D.h"

#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <visualization_msgs/MarkerArray.h>

#include <pcl_ros/transforms.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h> /*M test*/
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseArray.h> /*M test*/

#include "ros/time.h"


namespace darknet_ros_3d
{

Darknet3D::Darknet3D():
  nh_("~")
{
  initParams();

  darknet3d_pub_ = nh_.advertise<darknet_ros_3d_msgs::BoundingBoxes3d>(output_bbx3d_topic_, 100);
  markers_pub_ = nh_.advertise<visualization_msgs::MarkerArray>("/darknet_ros_3d/markers", 100);

  posearray_pub_ = nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/posearray", 100); //M Test

  yolo_sub_ = nh_.subscribe(input_bbx_topic_, 1, &Darknet3D::darknetCb, this);
  pointCloud_sub_ = nh_.subscribe(pointcloud_topic_, 1, &Darknet3D::pointCloudCb, this);

  last_detection_ts_ = ros::Time::now() - ros::Duration(60.0);
}


void
Darknet3D::initParams()
{
  input_bbx_topic_ = "/darknet_ros/bounding_boxes";
  output_bbx3d_topic_ = "/darknet_ros_3d/bounding_boxes";
  pointcloud_topic_ = "/r200/camera/depth_registered/points";
  working_frame_ = "odom";/*rs200_camera*/
  mininum_detection_thereshold_ = 0.5f;
  minimum_probability_ = 0.3f;

  nh_.param("darknet_ros_topic", input_bbx_topic_, input_bbx_topic_);
  nh_.param("output_bbx3d_topic", output_bbx3d_topic_, output_bbx3d_topic_);
  nh_.param("point_cloud_topic", pointcloud_topic_, pointcloud_topic_);
  nh_.param("working_frame", working_frame_, working_frame_);
  nh_.param("mininum_detection_thereshold", mininum_detection_thereshold_, mininum_detection_thereshold_);
  nh_.param("minimum_probability", minimum_probability_, minimum_probability_);
  nh_.param("interested_classes", interested_classes_, interested_classes_);


}

void
Darknet3D::pointCloudCb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  point_cloud_ = *msg;
}

void
Darknet3D::darknetCb(const darknet_ros_msgs::BoundingBoxes::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  last_detection_ts_ = ros::Time::now();
  original_bboxes_ = msg->bounding_boxes;
}

void
Darknet3D::calculate_boxes(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& cloud_pc2,
    const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloud_pcl,
    darknet_ros_3d_msgs::BoundingBoxes3d* boxes)
{
  boxes->header.stamp = cloud_pc2.header.stamp;
  boxes->header.frame_id = working_frame_;

  for (auto bbx : original_bboxes_)
  {
    if ((bbx.probability < minimum_probability_) ||
        (std::find(interested_classes_.begin(), interested_classes_.end(), bbx.Class) == interested_classes_.end()))
    {
      continue;
    }

    int center_x, center_y;

    center_x = (bbx.xmax + bbx.xmin) / 2;
    center_y = (bbx.ymax + bbx.ymin) / 2;

    int pcl_index = (center_y* cloud_pc2.width) + center_x;
    pcl::PointXYZRGB center_point =  cloud_pcl->at(pcl_index);

    if (std::isnan(center_point.x))
      continue;

    float maxx, minx, maxy, miny, maxz, minz;

    maxx = maxy = maxz =  -std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    minx = miny = minz =  std::numeric_limits<float>::max();

    for (int i = bbx.xmin; i < bbx.xmax; i++)
      for (int j = bbx.ymin; j < bbx.ymax; j++)
      {
        pcl_index = (j* cloud_pc2.width) + i;
        pcl::PointXYZRGB point =  cloud_pcl->at(pcl_index);

        if (std::isnan(point.x))
          continue;

        if (fabs(point.x - center_point.x) > mininum_detection_thereshold_)
          continue;

        maxx = std::max(point.x, maxx);
        maxy = std::max(point.y, maxy);
        maxz = std::max(point.z, maxz);
        minx = std::min(point.x, minx);
        miny = std::min(point.y, miny);
        minz = std::min(point.z, minz);
      }

    darknet_ros_3d_msgs::BoundingBox3d bbx_msg;
    bbx_msg.Class = bbx.Class;
    bbx_msg.probability = bbx.probability;
    bbx_msg.xmin = minx;
    bbx_msg.xmax = maxx;
    bbx_msg.ymin = miny;
    bbx_msg.ymax = maxy;
    bbx_msg.zmin = minz;
    bbx_msg.zmax = maxz;
    bbx_msg.x = (bbx_msg.xmax + bbx_msg.xmin) / 2.0;
    bbx_msg.y = (bbx_msg.ymax + bbx_msg.ymin) / 2.0;
    bbx_msg.z = (bbx_msg.zmax + bbx_msg.zmin) / 2.0;

    boxes->bounding_boxes.push_back(bbx_msg);

/*M test*/
    geometry_msgs::PoseArray posearray; 
    posearray.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    posearray.header.frame_id = "odom" ;

    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose; 

    pose.pose.position.x = (bbx_msg.xmax + bbx_msg.xmin) / 2.0;
    pose.pose.position.y = (bbx_msg.ymax + bbx_msg.ymin) / 2.0;
    pose.pose.position.z = (bbx_msg.zmax + bbx_msg.zmin) / 2.0;
    pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
    ROS_INFO("pose.w value: %.2f", pose.pose.orientation.w); //M Test
    ROS_INFO("pose.x value: %.2f", pose.pose.position.x); //M Test
    ROS_INFO("pose.y value: %.2f", pose.pose.position.y); //M Test
    ROS_INFO("pose.z value: %.2f", pose.pose.position.z); //M Test
    ROS_INFO("poseArray size: %i", posearray.poses.size()); //M Test
    posearray.poses.push_back(pose.pose);


    // PoseArray message for boundingbox centres /*M test*/
//    geometry_msgs::Pose pose; /*M test*/
//    pose.position.x = (bbx_msg.xmax + bbx_msg.xmin) / 2.0; /*M test*/
//    pose.position.y = (bbx_msg.ymax + bbx_msg.ymin) / 2.0; /*M test*/
//    pose.position.z = (bbx_msg.zmax + bbx_msg.zmin) / 2.0; /*M test*/
//   pose.orientation.w = 1.0; //No rotation atm. /*M test*/
//    bb_centres.poses.push_back(pose); /*M test*/
  }

}

void
Darknet3D::update()
{
  if ((ros::Time::now() - last_detection_ts_).toSec() > 2.0)
    return;

  if ((darknet3d_pub_.getNumSubscribers() == 0) &&
      (markers_pub_.getNumSubscribers() == 0))
    return;

  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 local_pointcloud;

  try
  {
    pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(working_frame_, point_cloud_, local_pointcloud, tfListener_);
  }
  catch(tf::TransformException& ex)
  {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Transform error of sensor data: " << ex.what() << ", quitting callback");
    return;
  }

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pcrgb(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::fromROSMsg(local_pointcloud, *pcrgb);

  darknet_ros_3d_msgs::BoundingBoxes3d msg;

  geometry_msgs::PoseArray posearray; //M Test

  calculate_boxes(local_pointcloud, pcrgb, &msg);

  darknet3d_pub_.publish(msg);

  posearray_pub_.publish(posearray); //M Test


  publish_markers(msg);
}

void
Darknet3D::publish_markers(const darknet_ros_3d_msgs::BoundingBoxes3d& boxes)
{
  visualization_msgs::MarkerArray msg;

  int counter_id = 0;
  for (auto bb : boxes.bounding_boxes)
  {
    visualization_msgs::Marker bbx_marker;

    bbx_marker.header.frame_id = boxes.header.frame_id;
    bbx_marker.header.stamp = boxes.header.stamp;
    bbx_marker.ns = "darknet3d";
    bbx_marker.id = counter_id++;
    bbx_marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE;
    bbx_marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
    bbx_marker.pose.position.x = (bb.xmax + bb.xmin) / 2.0;
    bbx_marker.pose.position.y = (bb.ymax + bb.ymin) / 2.0;
    bbx_marker.pose.position.z = (bb.zmax + bb.zmin) / 2.0;
    bbx_marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    bbx_marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    bbx_marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
    bbx_marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
    bbx_marker.scale.x = (bb.xmax - bb.xmin);
    bbx_marker.scale.y = (bb.ymax - bb.ymin);
    bbx_marker.scale.z = (bb.zmax - bb.zmin);
    bbx_marker.color.b = 0;
    bbx_marker.color.g = bb.probability * 255.0;
    bbx_marker.color.r = (1.0 - bb.probability) * 255.0;
    bbx_marker.color.a = 0.4;
    bbx_marker.lifetime = ros::Duration(0.5);

    msg.markers.push_back(bbx_marker);
  }

  markers_pub_.publish(msg);
}

};  // namespace darknet_ros_3d
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344735/republishing-custom-message-to-type-/posearray/) by [marcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/49229/marcs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `posearray` message structure in your `update()` method isn't the same as the local `posearray` message structure you declare and populate in `calculate_boxes()`. Instead of declaring a local `geometry_msgs::PoseArray` in `calculate_boxes()`, just add a pointer argument like you are already doing with your custom message. Then from `update()`, pass the pointer to the `PoseArray` you are actually publishing.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2020-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0